# inDesign ebook not printing font from character style

Tags: css, export, adobe, adobe-indesign

I have an inDesign document that uses a character style to change ü to wingdings which prints a check mark. This works perfectly throughout the document and when I export to PDF, but not in an eBook. In the eBook the check is just the regular ü. I am getting an error message about the css, but I don't see anyplace that addresses fonts in the export. Does anyone know of a way around this? Thank you!

Comment: It's probably best to use a unicode checkmark (✓) instead of wingdings to represent it. Ebooks are spotty with embedded fonts like wingdings. Also, this question probably belongs on superuser.com instead.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning superuser.com, didn't know about it. I will repost there. My document is created via XML Import and the unicode for a check doesn't print. The wingdings with unicode for ü is the only way I've gotten it to print.